# Time series aggregation : flatten "window" struct type in Scala/Spark dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

In order to aggregate a timeserie (for ex every 10min) I used "groupBy" and "window" as shown :

```
val df2 = df.groupBy(
  window($"timestamp", "10 minutes"))
  .avg("field")
```

df2.show() looks like

```
+-------------------------------------------+----------+
|                                     window|avg(field)|
+-------------------------------------------+----------+
| [2018-06-10 03:30:00, 2018-06-10 03:40:00]|22        |
| [2018-06-10 03:30:00, 2018-06-10 03:40:00]|42        |
| [2018-06-10 03:30:00, 2018-06-10 03:40:00]|60        | 
+-------------------------------------------+----------+
```

This is its schema :

```
root
 |-- window: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- avg(field): int (nullable = true)
```

I wanted to save it to csv but I can't :

```
CSV data source does not support struct<start:timestamp,end:timestamp>
```

Do you know how can I flatten the window column ? Or is there a better way to aggregate timeseries like that ?

Thank you very much

Comment: I've already seen this post. My problem is I don't know how to deal with "struct" type : 

  val stringify = udf((vs: StructType) => vs match {
    case null => null
    case _    => s"""[${vs.head}]"""
  })

is not working ...

Comment: Found it ! you can access struct by adding the col's name between parenthesis  : df.withColumn("window", $"window"("start"))